# My conditionals are being included in the HTML output by pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the the following code in a pug template:

```
body
    h1(style="text-align: center;") Invoice Number #{invoiceNum}
    table(id="addr-tbl")
        tr
            td(style="width:50%").
                #{vendor.name}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine1}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine2}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine3}<br>
                if (vendor.addrCity)
                    #{vendor.addrCity}
                if (vendor.addrState)
                    , #{vendor.addrState}
                if (vendor.addrPostalCode)
                    #{vendor.addrPostalCode}
                <br>
```

This outputs my `if` statements into the HTML. Then I tried this:

```
            td(style="width:50%").
                #{vendor.name}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine1}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine2}<br>
                #{vendor.addrLine3}<br>
            if (vendor.addrCity)
                |#{vendor.addrCity}
            if (vendor.addrState)
                |, #{vendor.addrState}
            if (vendor.addrPostalCode)
                | #{vendor.addrPostalCode}
            <br>
```

which doesn't output the `if` statement, but it also outputs `addrCity`, `addrState` and `addrPostalCode` outsite the `td` tag.

The aim is to output each of these address components (possibly followed/preceded by a comma) only if they're not `null`/`undefined`. Otherwise, nothing.

How can I do this in pug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `.` on your `td` is forcing the contents to be text. If you have a mix of text and code:

```
 td(style="width:50%")
   | #{vendor.name}<br>
   | ...
   | #{vendor.addrLine3}<br>
   if (vendor.addrCity)
     | #{vendor.addrCity}
```

Then you can be a lot more specific about what's code and what's text.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. On this aspect at least, I found pug's documentation as clear as mud. Could you point me where in the documentation I could have figured this out?

Comment: It's under [Plain Text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) in the "Block in a Tag" section.

Comment: Thanks again. Despite already having this knowledge from your answer, I still wouldn't have understood that text to mean what you have explained here... the documentation needs improvement, IMHO.